# Differences between Firefox and Chrome in the Omega theme

Tags: 7, theming

I'm building a site in Omega, and I'm having trouble understanding why Firefox is so much different than Chrome/IE. For example, in the menu bar, the font is fine and the text has plenty of room on the right side; in IE and Chrome, the font is much larger and the text wraps to another line. The display width doesn't seem to be that much different. Zooming in and out don't seem to matter.

Why does it seem to fit like it should in Firefox, but not IE/Chrome? How can I control that?

Comment: It's not related to Omega theme, not even Drupal

Comment: I understand, but I'm curious if Omega can deal with this somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I previously mentioned in comment, its not related to Omega nor Drupal, but you can still try to use [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css).

> A modern, HTML5-ready alternative to CSS resets (as used by Twitter
> Bootstrap, HTML5 Boilerplate, TweetDeck, Soundcloud, and many others)

Alrternatively as you didn't provide any link or capture, I suggest to check your styles and libraries list in your omega subtheme settings, go to `Appearance > THEMENAME > Settings` , under Toggle styles and Toggle Libraries